# Can a prvalue of type int be invoked?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Kind of ridiculous question but not when you ask MSVC, apparently. So, by which rule of the C++20 standard is the invocation of a prvalue of type `int` nonsensical?

```cpp
// clang: nope, gcc: nope, msvc: why not?
static_assert(requires { requires noexcept(int{}()); });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GEfqYc83e)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, we need to parse `int{}()` as an *expression* (the argument of a `noexcept` *unary-expression* is an *expression*). I won't bore you with the details, as it is what you'd expect: it's a *postfix-expression* of the form `postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )` (i.e. a function call) where the left *postfix-expression* (i.e. the function part) is `int{}` (which, as you know, is an `int` prvalue), and there is no *expression-list*.

Preliminaries established, in the current draft standard, we have [`[over.match.funcs]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#over.match.oper-1) (§12.2.2.3/1):

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to `[expr.compound]`.

The only operand of `int{}()` is `int{}`, being of type `int`, so there is no overload resolution step. Thus the `()` here is a genuine function call operator and is not replaced with an `operator()`. Following the reference now, we read in [`[expr.call]/1`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.call-1) (§7.6.1.3/1):

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of *initializer-clauses* which constitute the arguments to the function.
>
> The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer type. ...

`int` is certainly neither a function type nor a function pointer type, so the call `int{}()` is ill-formed.

Now, there's actually an explanation for MSVC's nonconforming behavior. Try compiling the following line!

```
int main() { int{}(); }
```

MSVC will accept it, but give you this warning

```
nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.  Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead
```

So it appears that, as a nonstandard extension to C++, MSVC does allow you to call an integer constant of value `0` (which `int{}` is), and the effect is a no-op (which explains why it can pass `noexcept`).

Comment: I would love to know the origin story of this extension. That seems... uh... bizarre.

Comment: However, there is no warning issued by MSVC (even when compiling with /permissive-) regarding the use of a nonstandard extension when merely checking for the validity of said expression (e.g.: with the use of a requires-clause). While such silent fallback mechanism might not technically be in violation of the standard (not really sure), it does illustrate really poor design of MSVC. As this could lead to some really surprising results when writing more generic code.